# How can I obtain more information from Break Mode exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I get a wierd runtime exception after I log in my app.

"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'"

This is that little popup and the Break Mode window opens. How can I obtain more information about the error, like the file that caused it, the line or something a little more useful

Comment: Use some logging framework, try-catch block and write exception message, innerexception and stack tract to log file inside the catch block. Open the logfile in text editor to see what is logged there

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what the InnerException has or check out the StackTrace to get more information regarding the error.

To get more details on the inner exception, open the visual studio watch window (in order to open the watch window, the debugger must be running or in break mode).